# VertX JUnit 5 MongoDB test does not complete (TimeoutException) or completes too early (testContext.awaitCompletion not working)

Tags: mongodb, promise, async-await, vert.x, junit5

**Background:**

During migration from JUnit4 to JUnit5 using VertX I read the migration guides which explain:

- how to use the changed `Promise` and `Future` Vertx interfaces
- how to `VertxTestContext`, `Vertx` auto-injection in Vertx Tests
- how to use `testContext.awaitCondition()`, `textContext.completing()`, `testContext.completeNow()` etc.

Having this information in mind I wrote the following test:

**Test Code:**

```
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.Future;

@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
class RestApiTest {

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpMongoDatabase() throws IOException {
        (...)
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext ctx) {
        vertx.deployVerticle(ApiVerticle.class.getName(), options, ctx.completing());
        return WebClient.create(vertx);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
        assertThat(vertx.deploymentIDs().size(), is(equalTo(2)));
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void stopMongoDatabase() {
        (...)
    }

    @Test
    void test(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
        Future<Void> insertFuture = insertTestData();
        future.setHandler(testContext.completing());
        // This ether throws a TimeoutException or does not block until the insert completed
        testContext.awaitCompletion(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // assert
        mongoClient.findOne(COLLECTION, QUERY, result -> {
             if (result.succeeded()) testContext.completeNow();
             else testContext.failNow();
        });
    }

    Future<Void> insertTestData() {
        Promise<Void> promise = Promise.promise();
        Future<Void> future = promise.future();
        mongoClient.insert(COLLECTION, QUERY, result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                promise.complete();
            } else {
                promise.fail();
            }
        });
        return future;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

- testContext.awaitCompletion() **ether throws a `TimeoutException`**
- or **does not block until the async insert completed** so that my assert returns successfully

**Question:**

- How can I wait for the async mongo query to complete before I continue with my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I am using the **VertX** `Promise` and `Future` classes:

- those classes **only work on a VertX `Verticle`**
- my `insertTestData()` method is **not executed on a Verticle**

One solution is to use the java.util.concurrent.`ReentrantLock` and `Condition` classes instead:

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        insertTestData(); // This is now synchronous as required
        // assert
        mongoClient.findOne(COLLECTION, QUERY, result -> {
             if (result.succeeded()) testContext.completeNow();
             else testContext.failNow();
        });
    }

    void insertTestData() {
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        mongoClient.insert(COLLECTION, QUERY, result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    condition.signal();
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            } else {
                fail();
            }
        });
        lock.lock();
        try {
            condition.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest: It took me so long to find the bug/solution which I documented here because I probably implicitly expected that the VertX `Promise` and `Future` classes would throw some kind of error or warning when they are used outside a `Verticle`.